# How to condense subdirectories

Tags: shell-script, directory

I have one directory with many sub-directories. All of those sub-directories contain files which each have unique names. I want to take all the files from all of the sub-directories and move them all to one directory.

There are a few hundred sub-directories, so I wouldn't want to do this by hand. How would I go about writing a shell script to do this? I'm using bash.

Answer (score 6):

`find` is the solution:

```
find /srcpath -type f -exec mv {} /dstpath \;
```

or better, if your `mv` has the `-t destination-dir` option:

```
find /srcpath -type f -exec mv -t /dstpath {} +
```

Answer (score 3):

The simple way, if there's a single level of subdirectories:

```
cd source_directory
mv -- */* /path/to/target/directory
```

If you want to move the files to the parent directory, that's `mv -- */* .`. Note that files or directories whose name begins with `.` (“dot files”) are excluded. To include them, in bash, run `shopt -s dotglob` first. In zsh, run `setopt glob_dots` first.

If you want to move files from subsubdirectories and so on recursively as well, with `zsh`:

```
cd source_directory
mv -- */**/*(^/) .
```

If you try to run the `mv` command and get an error like “command line too long”, you'll have to break it down. The simplest way is to use `find`. With GNU tools (non-embedded Linux and Cygwin):

```
find source_directory -mindepth 2 ! -type d \
  -exec mv -t /path/to/target/directory -- {} +
```

Comment: Mucking around with `mv` in a situation like this is not a terribly useful idea since it'll cheerfully move subdirectories, content and all.

Comment: @Shadur `mv` will only move subdirectories if it's passed subdirectories, which doesn't happen here (after Stephane's fix).

Answer (score 2):

```
#! /bin/sh

# set your output directory here
outdir=./Outdir 

# get a list of all the files (-type f)
# in subdirectories (-mindepth 1)
# who do not match the outdir  (-path $outdir -prune)
# and step through and execute a move
find . -mindepth 1 -path $outdir -prune -o -type f -exec mv '{}' $outdir \;
```

This will allow you to search from the present working directory, all the sub directories, 
and move the files to a sub directory in the same working directory ($outdir) - note the 
proceeding ./ on the path to make the -prune work properly.